# Using $sum and $cond to get $sum of values, not sum of instances in mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to use a combination of the $group and $project operators (unless there is a better alternative) to generate two values.

Consider a document data structure that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    openBalance: 22,
    customerResponsible: true
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    openBalance: 16,
    customerResponsible: false
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    openBalance: 10,
    customerResponsible: true
  },
  {
    _id: 4,
    openBalance: 20,
    customerResponsible: false
  },
]
```

What I'm trying to do is output a document with a value `customerOpenBalance`, which represents the total openBalance for documents where "customerResponsible" is `true`. And a value `agencyOpenBalance`, which represents the total openBalance where "customerResponsible" is set to `false`.

Now, I can do this in the `$group` stage:

```
"customerResponsibleOpenBalance" : { "$sum" : { "$cond" : [ "$customerResponsibile", 1, 0 ] }},
```

And then in a later `$project` stage do this:

```
"customerResponsibleOpenBalance" : { "$sum": "$customerResponsibleOpenBalance" }
```

But what this gives me is the `$sum` of the `instances`, rather than what I actually want, which is the $sum of the *values* found in `openBalance`, where, for the case of `customerResponsibleOpenBalance`, the boolean value `customerResponsible` I'm targeting is `true`.

How can I adjust this aggregation to get the `$sum` of the values found in `$openBalance`, rather than the `$sum` of the instances?

My full aggregation pipeline looks like this (the key stages are the $group in stage 6, and the $project, in stage 18:

db.transactions.aggregate(

```
  // Pipeline
  [
    // Stage 1
    {
      $match: {
        "openBalance": {
          "$ne": 0.0
        }
      }
    },

    // Stage 2
    {
      $lookup: {
        "from": "customers",
        "localField": "customer.id",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "customer"
      }
    },

    // Stage 3
    {
      $unwind: {
        "path": "$customer"
      }
    },

    // Stage 4
    {
      $lookup: {
        "from": "visits",
        "localField": "visit.id",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "visit"
      }
    },

    // Stage 5
    {
      $unwind: {
        "path": "$visit"
      }
    },

    // Stage 6
    {
      $group: {
        "_id": "$customer._id",
        "submissions": {
          "$push": "$submissions"
        },
        "staffMember": {
          "$first": "$staffMember.id"
        },
        "visit": {
          "$first": "$visit"
        },
        "openBalance": {
          "$sum": "$openBalance"
        },
        "customerResponsibleOpenBalance": {
          "$sum": {
            "$cond": ["$visit.customerResponsibility", 1, 0]
          }
        },
        "agencyResponsibleOpenBalance": {
          "$sum": {
            "$cond": ["$visit.customerResponsibility", 0, 1]
          }
        },
        "openClaims": {
          "$sum": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$gt": ["$submissions.0.responses.balance", 0.0]
              },
              "then": 1.0,
              "else": 0.0
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Stage 7
    {
      $addFields: {
        "payerInfo": "$submissions.0.details.agency._id"
      }
    },

    // Stage 8
    {
      $lookup: {
        "from": "agencies",
        "localField": "submissions.0.details.agency._id",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "agency"
      }
    },

    // Stage 9
    {
      $unwind: {
        "path": "$agency"
      }
    },

    // Stage 10
    {
      $addFields: {
        "claimSupervisor": "$agency.claims.supervisor"
      }
    },

    // Stage 11
    {
      $lookup: {
        "from": "staffmembers",
        "localField": "claimSupervisor",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "claimSupervisor"
      }
    },

    // Stage 12
    {
      $unwind: {
        "path": "$claimSupervisor"
      }
    },

    // Stage 13
    {
      $lookup: {
        "from": "customers",
        "localField": "_id",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "customer"
      }
    },

    // Stage 14
    {
      $unwind: {
        "path": "$customer"
      }
    },

    // Stage 15
    {
      $lookup: {
        "from": "locales",
        "localField": "customer.locale",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "locale"
      }
    },

    // Stage 16
    {
      $unwind: {
        "path": "$locale"
      }
    },

    // Stage 17
    {
      $lookup: {
        "from": "agencies",
        "localField": "agencies",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "agencies"
      }
    },

    // Stage 18
    {
      $project: {
        "customer": {
          "_id": 1.0,
          "name": 1.0
        },
        "agency": {
          "_id": 1.0,
          "name": 1.0,
          "transactionType": 1.0
        },
        "visit": {
          "_id": 1.0,
          "customerResponsibility": 1.0
        },
        "openBalance": 1.0,
        "openClaims": 1.0,
        "customerResponsibleOpenBalance": {
          "$sum": "$customerResponsibleOpenBalance"
        },
        "agencyResponsibleOpenBalance": {
          "$sum": "$agencyResponsibleOpenBalance"
        },
        "locale": {
          "_id": 1.0,
          "name": 1.0
        },
        "firstSubmission": {
          "$arrayElemAt": ["$submissions", 0.0]
        },
        "lastSubmission": {
          "$arrayElemAt": ["$submissions", -1.0]
        },
        "claimSupervisor": {
          "_id": 1.0,
          "name": 1.0
        }
      }
    },

    // Stage 19
    {
      $unwind: {
        "path": "$firstSubmission"
      }
    },

    // Stage 20
    {
      $unwind: {
        "path": "$lastSubmission"
      }
    },

    // Stage 21
    {
      $project: {
        "firstSubmission": {
          "details": 0.0,
          "responses": 0.0
        },
        "lastSubmission": {
          "details": 0.0,
          "responses": 0.0
        }
      }
    },
  ],

);
```

Comment: I have a feeling there's a whole bunch of things not quite right in the pipeline. If you could post some matching sample data with the desired output I am sure we could get this right for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, I was initially a little mislead by your sample data. Now, with the edited question and the full pipeline, I think all you only need to change from

```
"customerResponsibleOpenBalance" : { "$sum" : { "$cond" : [ "$customerResponsibile", 1, 0 ] }}
```

to

```
"customerResponsibleOpenBalance" : { "$sum" : { "$cond" : [ "$customerResponsibile", "$openBalance", 0 ] }},
```

Comment: That would get me a value for when customerResponsible is true, but I also need a value for when customerResponsible is false. How would I do that?

Comment: Two times wrong. ;) Kindly see the updated answer which explains what's going on here.

Comment: Yes. See the examples here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/. And also see my updated answer.

Comment: Ah, so you can pass an array to $cond. I didn't realize that.

Comment: There is no array...?! Can you potentially just strip out all the stages from 6 onwards and let me know what the output after stage 5 looks like?

Comment: "$cond" : [ "$customerResponsibile", "$openBalance", 0 ] -- that's an array.

Comment: I see. Of course, yes. Check the two top-most syntax examples. You have a choice: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/

Comment: That worked for the "true" case. Thanks! Now I'm trying to figure out how to get the value when "$customerResponsible" is false. Tried this, but the syntax is off:
"agencyResponsibleOpenBalance" : { "$sum" : { "$cond" : [ "$customerResponsibile" : false, "$openBalance", 0 ] }},

Comment: Just swap the `if` and `else` bits: `"customerResponsibleOpenBalance" : { "$sum" : { "$cond" : [ "$customerResponsibile" : 0, "$openBalance" ] }}`

Comment: Perfect. Much appreciated, @drickless.